# Password Validation - Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

I want to validate password field. I have tried following code, but getting message that "Your password must satisfy the following...............", even though i enter a correct password format.

```
var re = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,8}$/;

     if ( !re.test(rpassword) )
       {
       alert('Your password must satisfy the following. \n\n* Password should be 4 to 8 character long. \n* Password should have at least one alphabet. \n* Password should have at least one numeric value. \n* Password should  have special characters.');
       return false;
  }
```

Not getting what is wrong with this code. Please help !!

Comment: Where does the variable "rpassword" come from?

Comment: What password are you trying? First thing to figure out is whether your password gets passed the regex.

Comment: "password" is password field on my form. I used function checkForm()
{ var rpassword;  rpassword=password;  }

Comment: @JAA Is that generated output?

Comment: @User729776 I dont get your comment...  your checkForm() function is not going to have the same constraints as the OP

Comment: 4 to 8 characters? If I want a longer password, I'm not allowed to? And what do you *exactly* mean by “special characters”? And still, how do you get the password from the password field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want:

```
if ( !re.test(rpassword.value) ) {
  // ...
}
```

?? You say that "rpassword" is a reference to the password **element** in your form. If so, then you have to get its "value" attribute first.

Answer (score 1):

could you try this regular expression?

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{4,8}$/
```